# No such file or directory Django AWS S3 Boto3 Upload

Tags: javascript, django, amazon-s3, boto3, cloudflare

I tried everything, its not working, and i think i know why but i dont know how to fix it, im using [this tutorial to upload in chunks](https://dev.to/shubhamkshatriya25/ajax-file-upload-in-chunks-using-django-with-a-progress-bar-4nhi) to bypass the Cloudflare upload limitation of 100mb file

```
def create_post(request):
# s3_client=boto3.client('s3')
s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name=settings.AWS_S3_REGION_NAME, aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                      aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
categories_1 = Category.objects.all()
if request.method == 'POST':   
    file = request.FILES['file'].read()
    file_name_s3 = request.POST['filename']
    fileName= request.POST['filename'].replace(' ', '')
    fileName_STR = re.sub("[^A-Z]", "", fileName,0,re.IGNORECASE) + '.mp4'
    existingPath = request.POST['existingPath']
    end = request.POST['end']
    image = request.FILES.get('image', False)
    imageName = request.FILES.get('imagename', False)

    if image != False:
            image = request.FILES['image'].read()
            imageName= request.POST['imagename'].replace(' ', '')
    else:
            pass
    title = request.POST['title']
    tags = request.POST['tags']
    categories = parse_ids(request.POST['categories'])
    description = request.POST['description']
    nextSlice = request.POST['nextSlice']


    if file=="" or fileName_STR=="" or existingPath=="" or end=="" or nextSlice=="":
        res = JsonResponse({'data':'Invalid Request'})
        return res
    else:
        if existingPath == 'null':
            path = 'media/uploads/video_files/' + fileName
            
            if image != False: 
                with open(path, 'wb+') as destination: 
                    destination.write(file)
                imagePath = 'media/thumbnail/' + imageName
            else:
                pass
            if image:
                with open(imagePath, 'wb+') as destination:
                    destination.write(image)
            else: 
                pass
            
            
            object_name = Path.joinpath(BASE_DIR, file_name_s3)
```

## handles the upload...................

```
            path = 'media/uploads/video_files/' + fileName_STR
            with open(object_name, 'rb') as destination:
                s3_client.upload_file(object_name ,bucket,fileName_STR)
```

## ............................................

```
            FileFolder = Post()
            FileFolder.video = 'uploads/video_files/'+fileName_STR
            FileFolder.existingPath = fileName_STR
            FileFolder.eof = end
            FileFolder.title = title
            FileFolder.author = request.user
            FileFolder.description = description

            if image == False:
                FileFolder.thumbnail = None
            else:
                FileFolder.thumbnail = 'thumbnail/' + imageName

            FileFolder.approved = True
            FileFolder.save()
            tag_list = taggit.utils._parse_tags(tags)
            FileFolder.tags.add(*tag_list)
            categories_post = Category.objects.filter(id__in=categories)
            if categories_post:
                for category in categories_post:
                    FileFolder.categories.add(category)
            if int(end):
                res = JsonResponse({'data':'Uploaded Successfully','existingPath': fileName})
            else:
                res = JsonResponse({'existingPath': fileName_STR})
            return res
        else:
            path = 'media/uploads/video_files/' + existingPath
            model_id = Post.objects.get(existingPath=existingPath)
            if model_id.title == title:
                if not model_id.eof:
                    with open(path, 'ab+') as destination: 
                        destination.write(file)
                    if int(end):
                        model_id.eof = int(end)
                        model_id.save()
                        res = JsonResponse({'data':'Uploaded Successfully','existingPath':model_id.existingPath})
                    else:
                        res = JsonResponse({'existingPath':model_id.existingPath})    
                    return res
                else:
                    res = JsonResponse({'data':'EOF found. Invalid request'})
                    return res
            else:
                res = JsonResponse({'data':'No such file exists in the existingPath'})
                return res
return render(request, 'main/create_post.html', {'categories': categories_1})
```

It gives me

> with open(object_name, 'rb') as destination:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> '/home/mrlonely/Desktop/lumen/lumen/Bones -
> TheArtOfCremation-tqSpI1Jm0YE-1080p.mp4'

For now i just want to save the videos to S3, but the same procces is the same with images i think

Comment: `with open(object_name, 'rb') as destination` is attempting to open a local file named "object_name", which won't exist.  Get rid of this line and de-indent the line after it.

Comment: I tried that it gives me     
`return os.stat(filename).st_size
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/mrlonely/Desktop/lumen/lumen/Bones - TheArtOfCremation-tqSpI1Jm0YE-1080p.mp4'`